# C++ Pass by reference as opposed to pass by value/pointer

Tags: c++

Since a pass by reference is not pass by value, the stack should not be involved in the former and it should be faster. This also means a pass by reference should be resolved at compile time rather than run time, so code like the following should be illegal (plus the requirement that references must be intialised when they are declared):

```
void foo(int &i)
{
  cout << i;
}

main()
{
  int i;
  int array[5];
  cout << "Make sure you enter something between 0 and 4:";
  cin >> i;
  foo(array[i]);
}
```

If the above code compiles/works, we can be sure the reference is implemented as a pointer, which becomes pass by value? Comments please. Is there a compiler setting to not let the above code compile, i.e. to keep references true aliases?

Edit: Better way to ask this question is: Is pass by reference any faster than pass by pointer? If yes, how?

Edit2: Is the stack always involved when using reference parameters?

Edit3: Am I right in concluding that a reference is just a pointer except when it can be optimised "away" by the compiler? Can someone please explain in simple terms with an example what "optimised away" means?

Edit4: I have concluded references are just "syntatic sugar". There is no speed up. If somebody could explain in simple terms with an example what "optimised away" means?

Comment: read foo(i) as foo(array[i])

Comment: Why not *edit* your question to fix problems with it?

Comment: Regarding your question, references *could* be implemented using pointers, and so the compiler still need to copy the pointer, so for small native types there's no speedup using references. On the other hand the compiler might optimize your simple code. Also, if you don't modify the value inside the function, consider passing a reference to a constant instead (e.g. `const int& i` in your case), as this might enable the compiler even further optimizations, as well as adding some semantic information to the programmer using the function.

Comment: Those are some wild assumptions you're jumping to. It's unspecified how references are implemented, and yes, they are usually implemented as pointers. I really don't understand where you came up with this from - *reference should be resolved at compile time*. It's perfectly legal to form a reference to an object at runtime.

Comment: Another way to ask this question is: Is pass by reference any faster than pass by pointer? If yes, how?

Comment: `cin << i;` is illegal , `cin` is only an output stream

Comment: Doing `++i;` in the function should be enough to convince you that pass-by-reference is different to pass-by-value. References are true aliases. `i` in the function and `array[i]` in main refer to the same object.

Comment: Praetorian, I agree, I dont understand the compiler, so "reference should be resolved at compile time" should have been avoided.

Comment: Matt, I was referring to pass by pointer when i mentioned pass by value.

Comment: Joachim, your statement "references could be implemented using pointers, and so the compiler still need to copy the pointer, so for small native types there's no speedup using references" is quite helpful, but it suggests to me that references are always implemented using pointers. Is the stack always involved when using reference parameters.

Comment: I think that the problem is not in the reference part, but in the word _stack_. The compiler is not required to use a stack to call functions. It may use a stack, and most compilers will do so for many functions. If that is the case, then references will likely be compiled just like pointers. But if the function is inlined, for example, then no stack and no pointer-like reference.

Comment: Note that C has references too; you just can't create named ones like you can in C++. e.g. after `int x; int* y = &x;`, the expression `*y` is a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `i` in `main` is in the range [0, 4], the `i` in `foo` refers to one of the elements of the `array`.

It's legal for a reference to refer to an uninitialised variable.

It's not legal to *use* it. So the statement `cout << i;` is undefined.

Whether or not this is resolved at *compile* time is up to the compiler: the standard does not mandate this.

Comment: Hi Bathsheba, my question really is:  Is pass by reference any faster than pass by pointer? If yes, how? If no, why did C++ come up with it?